# Codeception ignores "required" from input fields

Tags: codeception

I have form which contains HTML5 "required" in input type text and password. But when I run test cases using codeception, it is not considering that required property and submits the form.

Comment: Test it with WebDriver module.

Comment: can you show me how to do it? m new to codeception.

Comment: http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver

Comment: thanks @Naktibalda I will try and get back

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior! What do you Codeception to do? The 'required' trait should be processed by the browser. If you submit an incomplete form, something happens - it's not automatically an error, depending on what you're trying to do.